# How prevent users from deploying to a Deployment group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Let say I have 2 Deployment Groups Named QC and Production, each one contains X number of servers.
I also have a Release Pipeline with 2 stages QCStage,ProductionStage.

How can I set my permissions,**on Deployment Group Level,** so that users can't deploy to Production?

I can achieve this using "Pre-deployment approvals" on each stage but I have hundreds of Pipelines,
we can't be setting permissions for every stage for every pipeline

**Update:**
This doesn't see to be supported on Azure DevOps,a new Feature Suggestion has been created:
[Prevent users from deploying to a Deployment group using Deployment Group Permissions (not on each Stage)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/969178/prevent-users-from-deploying-to-a-deployment-group.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How prevent users from deploying to a Deployment group

Answering this question at two different scope levels.

**Scope 1**:

Take a simple sample, there has 2 deployment groups in your project: `QA` and `Product`.

If what you want is some of users can deploy to `QA` but not `Product`, I'm afraid this hasn't been expanded into azure devops until now.

Now for azure devops service, we provide 3 permission level controlled: **collection**, **project** and **object**. `Deployment group` is the one which belong to object level permission. We haven't provided more **granular** permissions control, like setting permission on one specific deployment group at this scenario.

---

**Scope 2**:

Just restrict someone to deploy a release.

As you know, `Deployment group` are used for a release stage. In this scenario, in order to control who can/can't deploy a release, please use the [release permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#release-permissions). BUT, there has one disadvantage that it work only for manually initiated releases.

[image]

So, I'm afraid **Approvals** on release stage is another and better option for you to make use until now.

---

Comment: Thanks Merlin, I'll submit a ticket on developercommunity for this

Comment: @GeorgeVovos. Welcome:-) You can share your suggestion ticket link here. I'm sure there must others who has same request with you. Then they can vote it and raise its priority.

Comment: Created a Feature Suggestion for this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/969178/prevent-users-from-deploying-to-a-deployment-group.html